# Is it possible to Share Android phone 3G internet connection to multiple clients (tabs/computers) via bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth-tethering

I want to share my android phone 3G internet connection (via bluetooth) so that multiple clients (other android phones/tabs/laptops) can access shared internet simultaneously.

Is it possible to have the above?

Comment: I don't think the phone will let you connect to multiple bluetooth devices at the same time. So sharing the internet with multiple devices via bluetooth probably isn't possible. haven't got any proof either way.

Answer (score 1):

There's the bluetooth PAN profile which allows just that.
It is included with CM7+ and from Android 4.0 onwards (or already 3.0?). Bluetooth PAN's host (the device that provides the internet) acts as a router which does NAT + issue dhcp adresses for its clients.

There are also  *Bluetooth DUN profile* apps that allow this (they provide a **virtual** GSM modem and may also allow for more than 1 connection at a time):
See host+client [BlueDUN apps from Mirko Solazzi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Mirko+Solazzi)